# Is there a Node.js/Express.js library/framework for quick CRUD API setup like Django REST Framework?

Tags: node.js, django, express, rest, crud

I am currently working on a project in Node.js with Express.js, and I'm looking for a library or framework that can streamline the process of creating REST API endpoints for CRUD operations on my models, similar to how Django REST Framework simplifies this task in Django.

In Django, I can quickly set up a model like this:

```py
from django.db import models

class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then, I create a serializer:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from songs.models import Artist

class ArtistSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'name', 'songs']
```

And finally, a viewset:

```py
class ArtistViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows songs to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Artist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArtistSerializer

    filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter]
    ordering_fields = ['name']
    ordering = ['-name']
```

With these few lines of code, I can create API endpoints for creating, reading, updating, and deleting Artist records, as well as add sorting and filtering functionality. It's a very convenient and efficient approach.

I'm wondering if there is a similar library or framework in the Node.js/Express.js ecosystem that offers a similar level of simplicity and ease of use. I find that in Node.js, there tends to be more boilerplate code and complexity when setting up similar functionality.

Additionally, I'm also curious if there is a Node.js equivalent to Django Djoser, which simplifies user authentication and provides endpoints for tasks like user creation, deletion, updating, JWT token generation, and more with minimal setup. In Django, I can achieve this by adding Djoser to my installed apps and configuring it in my URLs.

Any recommendations or insights into libraries, frameworks, or approaches that can help achieve these goals in a Node.js/Express.js project would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!